Retrieving Attribute from closest feature or with most overlap form another layer
I am trying to use the Field calculator to retrieve an attribute from the closest feature in another layer.  I have had the most success using Overlay_Nearest, but the array it returns does not use the Centroid to determine the closest feature or use the amount of overlap to prioritise.  I have one feature that overlaps two from the layer I am targeting and it result is an array where the first attribute is the feature it just barely touches where I want the attribute of the feature it overlaps over 50%.
For example: Overlay_Nearest('Target_Layer',"Attribute",3) results in ['A','B','C'], where I only want to return the result from the closest, which is usually the first unless the feature overlaps two.  Then it is random, and could result in ['A','B'], or it could be ['B','A'], even if the feature only overlaps B by 1% of its area so I can't say the first value in the array is the closest.

I have a solution for overlapping (and not overlapping) polygons, where you get any data from your target layer for the closest feature (if there is no overlap) or the features with the largest overlap. All you need is an ID field for each feature in each layer. This can be done pretty easily. Tip: use 'src_id'/'target_id' or something similar as field names, since calling the fields just 'id' can become very convoluted in the end.
I list the steps below, but you can also use the model builder if you need to do this several times.
First, use the Intersection tool with the source layer as input and the target layer as overlay. Add a new field to the resulting layer, where you calculate the area ($area) for each intersecting part.
Second, use the Aggregate tool on the intersection layer with the area information. Use the ID field from your source layer as group. In the 'Aggregates' window, chose the ID fields from both your source and target layer, as well as the area field. For the ID fields use "first_value" as aggregate function and for the area use "maximum". The output is a layer containing the ID for your source layer and the corresponding ID of the feature with largest overlap area.
Third, use Join attributes by field value on the source layer and the layer from the previous step. Use the respective source ID fields to join the information. Now you obtain a layer, that is spatially identical to your source layer but it also contains the information which features from your target layer overlaps the most with your source layer.
Fourth, since the information for non-overlapping features is missing I used an altered version of your expression to get the ID of the nearest non-overlapping feature. Here is the expression I used on the field with the target-ID in my joined layer: case when target_id is null then overlay_nearest('target_lyr', "target_id")[0] else target_id end (if my target-ID is missing due to no overlap, add the target-ID from the nearest feature, else keep the value in target_id).
This should result in your joined layer having the ID of the closest feature from your target layer or the ID of the feature with the largest overlap from your target layer.
Finally, you can set up a join (left click on the joined layer > "Properties" > "Joins") where you can use the ID from the previous step to get the desired information from your target layer.
EDIT - Since you mentioned centroids in your question: you can also calculate the centroids for each feature beforehand and then use the centroids for the respective steps described above.
